# Can't pass working directory to start-process

Tags: powershell

Here's my powershell function

```
function conRun ([string]$fwd=$conFolder, [switch]$NoNewWindow)
{
start-process java -ArgumentList '--jar myProject.jar', 'spring.profiles.active=prof1,prof2' -WorkingDirectory $fwd -PassThru -NoNewWindow:$NoNewWindow
}
```

I supposed it is to run java from `$conFolder` directory where the jar file is. But it doesn't. Runs in the current directory and fails instead. Do I misunderstand `-WorkingDirectory` somehow?

Comment: I just tried out your code and it worked for me when I set a $conFolder variable. When you run a test, can you try throwing a `"write-host $fwd;write-host $confolder"` in the line prior to the line in your function to see that the variables are set properly?

Comment: Found it. The problem was in the broken jar. For some reason it displayed exception in the current folder - that confused me. Rebuilt the jar correctly and everything runs just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is perfectly fine from my point of view.

I would like you to check :

1. jar myProject.jar,
2. spring.profiles.active=prof1,prof2

I think the issue is with them only cause when I tried with any other Jar with my local profile, it worked properly.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it was the broken jar file.